# Format html content from database using prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, prawn, html-sanitizing, html-safe

How can render HTML content from database in a prawn document

```
class PdfReport < Prawn::Document
  def initialize user
    super()
    text user.description #=> "<p>It's an html content</p>"
  end
end
```

The output i am getting from the above code is a string with HTML tags. I want something like `html_safe`. Is it possible in `Prawn`?

Answer (score 0):

The html paragraph tag doesn't work in prawn. If you're looking for how to create a separation between paragraphs, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49683036 which shows how to vertically measure text boxes (and formatted text boxes) and move the cursor accordingly.

But prawn can interpret some html tags such as bold:

```
s = "<b>It's an html content</b>"

text s # "<b>It's an html content</b>"
```

`text s, :inline_format => true #` **It's an html content**

Comment: using `:inline_format => true`, it doesn't recognize special symbols. For example, I want to show pound currency symbol instead of &#163; Any idea how can I achieve?

Comment: I wish Prawn was better at supporting html notation. I think they have taken a stance that it's a problem for derivative projects to solve - very unfortunate.  Just guessing but I would try copy and paste the symbol into your document rather than trying to represent it as an HTML entity.  If you're generating it in rails make sure your encoding is UTF-8.