# Prawn - Move cursor down after text_box expand

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, ruby-on-rails-5, prawn

I'm generating PDF's using the Prawn Gem and I'm unable to find a way to move the `cursor` down after `text_box` expands from overflow text, similar to the way a regular `text` call would.

**Text_box example**

```
pad(5) {
  text_box payable, :at => [bounds.left, cursor], :width => 540, :height => 15, :overflow => :expand, inline_format: true
}

move_down(15)

pad(5) {
  text_box address, :at => [bounds.left, cursor], :width => 250, :height => 15, :overflow => :expand, inline_format: true
  text_box city, :at => [250, cursor], :width => 100, :height => 15, :overflow => :expand, inline_format: true
  text_box state, :at => [350, cursor], :width => 75, :height => 15, :overflow => :expand, inline_format: true
  text_box zip, :at => [425, cursor], :width => 110, :height => 15, :overflow => :expand, inline_format: true
}
```

So above, I have to `pad` and `move_down` from the `text_box payable` in order for the next set of text_boxes to be formatted correctly without overlapping. If I use a straight `text` call on the `payable` string then the cursor moves down after all of the text is rendered, as expected.

The reason I'm using `text_box` over regular `text` is so that I can position text side by side on the same line. While this works great for strings thats all fit on a single line, it doesn't seem to play out well if one of those areas expands the `text_box` downwards because the cursor just starts at the next text line instead of below the expanded text_box.

Any insight or suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You've probably figured out something by now but I'm also new to Prawn and had the same question so hopefully this will help someone else. This example shows both a text box and a formatted text box. There is probably somehow a better way but this is working for me.

```
  txt1 = "u" * 250
  txt2 = "v" * 600
  txt3 = "w" * 100
  txt4 = "x" * 500
  txt5 = "y" * 200
  txt6 = "z" * 400

  stroke_horizontal_rule

  options = {:document=>@pdf, :at=>[0,cursor]}
  text_box(txt1, options)
  measure = Prawn::Text::Box.new(txt1, options)
  measure.render(:dry_run => true)
  move_down(measure.height)

  options = {:document=>@pdf, :at=>[0,cursor]}
  text_box(txt2, options)
  measure = Prawn::Text::Box.new(txt2, options)
  measure.render(:dry_run => true)
  move_down(measure.height)

  options = {:document=>@pdf, :at=>[0,cursor]}
  text_box(txt3, options)
  measure = Prawn::Text::Box.new(txt3, options)
  measure.render(:dry_run => true)
  move_down(measure.height)

  array = [{:text=>txt4, :size=>12}]
  options = {:document=>@pdf, :at=>[0,cursor]}
  formatted_text_box(array, options)
  measure = Prawn::Text::Formatted::Box.new(array, options)
  measure.render(:dry_run => true)
  move_down(measure.height)

  array = [{:text=>txt5, :size=>16}]
  options = {:document=>@pdf, :at=>[0,cursor]}
  formatted_text_box(array, options)
  measure = Prawn::Text::Formatted::Box.new(array, options)
  measure.render(:dry_run => true)
  move_down(measure.height)

  array = [{:text=>txt6, :size=>12}]
  options = {:document=>@pdf, :at=>[0,cursor]}
  formatted_text_box(array, options)
  measure = Prawn::Text::Formatted::Box.new(array, options)
  measure.render(:dry_run => true)
  move_down(measure.height)

  stroke_horizontal_rule
```

Comment: When I try to execute this, I get an error: "undefined method `text_direction' for nil:NilClass'.  Has something changed or am I missing something?

Comment: Which line of code raised the exception? It is true that text_direction is not defined for nil. So we need to figure out which variable is nil.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you're missing the reference to the document itself. Try adding "@pdf = self" as the first line in the document.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You made my day! Thanks for this answer!